# Baseclass Constructor implicitly called

Tags: c++

I am working on a large project and throughout the code we have the classes typedef the baseclass and call its constructor in the initializer list. Why is this? I built an example below showing what is generally done. As far as I can tell no difference in constructors happened. What is the benefit? I tried google but yielded no results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        printf("A Constructed\n");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:

    typedef A super;

    B()
    :super()
    {
        printf("B Constructed\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"What is the benefit?"_ That you can rely on this being done :-P ...

Comment: But of course it would call the base class constructor? Would it not? Is that not how the c++ standard works?

Comment: Are you asking why the constructor of `A` was called? Or are you asking why they rename `A` as `super`?

Comment: Why as the constructor of A called? C++ will do that automatically. Why do they do it themselves.

Comment: Is it always called that way, with no arguments?

Comment: Yes it always has no arguments.

Comment: My guess: a Java-educated lead tech that dictates coding standards is forced to use C++, but holds it in contempt for the sin of being different from Java. Move along, nothing to see here.

Comment: Then I can't think of a reason. Maybe someone who doesn't know C++ very well coded it?

Comment: That seems unlikely to me, this was built form the ground up by leading c++ developers.

Comment: Who apparently love java =). if you are going to use BaseClass default constructor then 100% useless to do such a thing. It's just a coding convention. Maybe someplace else you use non-default constructor. Maybe a lot of your developpers are from java / python and the lead guys decided it would be less confusing for them. Why don't you ask him ?

Comment: Have never seen a C++ developer useing "super".

Comment: If you know the people who havve built the software, why just not ask them?

Comment: Well I asked the person in charge of me and he did not seem to have a answer so I guess I will remove it. I will see if the lead architect cares at lunch.

Comment: Have a constructive discussion with the lead architect first. You don't want to ruffle too many feathers.

Comment: I asked and the answer was "to be explicit" while another programmer mentioned that it allows you to be able to tell if the class inherits from another in the CPP.

Answer (score 0):

class `A` is part of class `B`.

It would lead to very unstable code if the constructor to `A` was not called when constructing an instance of `B`. (For example, all member data of `A` would be uninitialised).

You *can* specify which constructor of `A` to use if you need to though, by using a base member initialiser.

In your case, using the base member initialiser is superfluous: you could write

```
 B()
 {
     printf("B Constructed\n");
 }
```

Comment: What I dont understand is that is the base class? The base class constructor will get called either way? The printf was the same before and after adding that constructor? Why are they adding it manually instead of letting it happen automatically.

Comment: Yes, but the question is why is the default ctor explicitly called. It gets called implicitly regardless.

Comment: Indeed. The question code contains redundant steps. I'd advise your removing them: it's only causing confusion. Looks like to me that some smart alec is trying to make C++ code look like Java.

Comment: I imagine they have a reason for putting them in. This code base was put together by some of leading members of the industry. I would not presume to remove there code without understanding why they did it.